# Sqlalchemy using ~ with and_, or_

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have an expression:

```
recent_oa = db_session.query(exists().where(
    and_(
        and_(Jobs.candidate_id == candidate_id, Jobs.interview_type == 'EVALUATION', Jobs.disposition_date < datetime.now()-timedelta(days=1)),
        ## I want this to evaluate to be True
        and_(~Jobs.candidate_id == candidate_id, Jobs.interview_type == 'IN_HOUSE', Jobs.disposition_date > '2017-01-01'),
        ## and I want this to evaluate to False    
    )
)).scalar()

recent_oa
>> True
```

so that `recent_oa` will evaluate to be `True`

I want to create multiple conditions that if the first line evaluates to be `True` and then the rest of the lines evaluate to be `False`, `recent_oa` will evaluate as `True`

How would I write that expression? the way I have it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: So you want `if a and not b and not c ...`?

Comment: And should `Jobs.candidate_id == candidate_id` be negated (as well) or did you mean to negate the whole `and_(~Jobs.candidate_id == candidate_id, Jobs.interview_type == 'IN_HOUSE', Jobs.disposition_date > '2017-01-01')` expression?

Comment: Next question: what is your database schema here and what conditions should return `True` here? I presume there can be multiple rows in the `Jobs` table per candidate. Should there be *no rows at all* with the second condition? Because currently you are filtering out rows with the second condition but only match the first condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to *prefix* the expression you need to invert with `~`, so `~ and_(...)`.

Note that there are operators and functions for all boolean logic operators. `~` is also available as the [`not_()` function](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.not_), and similarly, `and_()` can be expressed with `&`, and `or_()` can be expressed with `|`. I'd stick with one style or the other, not both.

So your requirements can be expressed as

```
and_(
    and_(
        Jobs.candidate_id == candidate_id,
        Jobs.interview_type == 'EVALUATION',
        Jobs.disposition_date < datetime.now()-timedelta(days=1)
    ),

    not_(
        and_(
            not_(Jobs.candidate_id == candidate_id),
            Jobs.interview_type == 'IN_HOUSE',
            Jobs.disposition_date > '2017-01-01'
        )
    )
)
```

or as

```
(
    (
        (Jobs.candidate_id == candidate_id)
        & (Jobs.interview_type == 'EVALUATION')
        & (Jobs.disposition_date < datetime.now()-timedelta(days=1))
    )

    & (
        ~ (
            ~ (Jobs.candidate_id == candidate_id)
            & (Jobs.interview_type == 'IN_HOUSE')
            & (Jobs.disposition_date > '2017-01-01')
        )
    )
)
```

Because the `~`, `&` and `|` operators have a [lower precedence than comparison operators](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) you do have to use `(...)` parentheses around each of the tests above to make sure the operators apply to the whole `column == value` and `column < value` tests.

I'm not 100% certain you meant to use `not_(Jobs.candidate_id == candidate_id)`, but if you did, then I'd just use `!=` there, so `Jobs.candidate_id != candidate_id` and drop the `not_()` condition on that test.

Next, the query is probably not going to give the right results anyway. It'll tell you if there are 1 or more rows that match your criteria, so rows where the candidate id matches, and there are specific conditions on the interview type and disposition date. What it will *not* do is tell you if there are **only** such rows that match. So if there are rows like this:

```
 candidate_id  |  disposition_date |  interview_type
---------------|-------------------|-----------------
 42            | 2018-01-01        | EVALUATION
 42            | 2018-01-02        | IN_HOUSE
```

then you get `True` because there is 1 row that matches your criteria. The `IN_HOUSE` row is filtered out. You won't get `False` here because it doesn't matter that the other row exists to the filter.

In that case you want to use the `NOT` expression boolean logic on separate `EXISTS` clauses, **not the conditions**, so the existence of the second row results in a `False` result countering the `True` for the other row:

```
SELECT id
FROM jobs
WHERE
    EXISTS(candidate_id = ? AND interview_type = ? AND disposition_date < ?)
    AND NOT EXISTS(candidate_id = ? AND interview_type = ? AND disposition_date > ?)
```

so create *two separate exists queries*:

```
candidate = db_session.query(Jobs).filter(Jobs.candidate_id == candidate_id)
has_evaluation = (
    candidate
    .filter(Jobs.interview_type == 'EVALUATION')
    .filter(Jobs.disposition_date < datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1))
)
has_inhouse = (
    candidate
    .filter(Jobs.interview_type == 'IN_HOUSE')
    .filter(Jobs.disposition_date > '2017-01-01')
)
recent_oa = (
    db_session.query(Jobs.id)
    .filter(has_evaluation.exists())
    .filter(not_(has_inhouse.exists())) # or .filter(~has_inhouse.exists())
    .scalar()
)
```

This uses the [`Query.exists()` method](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.exists) to produce the separate `EXISTS` conditions.

Comment: I see. I didn't think to the put the `~` outside the `(and_(...))` statement. Thanks!

Comment: to be clear, I have a list of `candidate_id` that I'm checking against my database to see if certain criteria is met. I'm not querying the database for a list of id's